# Property addControl does not exist on type AbstractControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested FormGroup which looks like this:

```
this.formGroup: FormGroup: {
    // ...
    controls: {
        "GENERAL_AND_PERSONAL_QUESTIONS": { // FormGroup object... }
    }
}
```

To the top level FormGroup I can easily add controls like this:

```
this.formGroup.addControl(tab.id, this.formBuilder.group({}));
```

However, to the child formGroup I can't add any controls for some reason. I try to add them like this:

```
// tab.id = "GENERAL_AND_PERSONAL_QUESTIONS";
this.formGroup.get(tab.id).addControl(segment.id, this.formBuilder.group({}));
```

But it always throws a compile error saying:

```
Property 'addControl' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: In my opinion, these two form objects do not match at all. Where is `controls` and `GENERAL_AND_PERSONAL_QUESTIONS` when you are trying to add a control? What even is `formGroup`, I see no use of FormBuilder there? :)

Answer (score 8):

`FormGroup` extended class from `AbstractControl` has [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) and this method is not part of parent class `AbstractControl`. So when you use the method [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get), the returned element is an `AbstractControl`, not `FormGroup`, so you should ensure the returned element is a `FormGroup` and cast it properly to use addControl method.

With this in mind, you can use addControl, adding in your code something like this:

```
abstractControl : AbstractControl = this.formGroup.get(tab.id);
if(abstractControl instanceof FormGroup){
    (<FormGroup>abstractControl).addControl(segment.id, this.formBuilder.group({}));
}
```

I made this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cSRkIc9o3UDQLW9pexQr) to clarify and 
exemplify what I mean in the  code above. The example is in test method in src/app.ts

Comment: The problem is that it's giving me a compile error, so .addControl just does not work, not even with the cast...

Comment: No, now it's another one: ´this.formGroup.addControl(tab.id, this.formBuilder.group({}));´ throws the following error now: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined

Comment: I update the answer to link a plunker, you can see the cast and the check in test method in src/app.ts. I hope this solve any doubt you have

Comment: @dave0688 this is another error, not related with the question. Could you update the question to clarify this new error?